# why different versions of GNOME are both on my computer?

Tags: fedora, gnome

I am using Fedora 37 workstation (**installed directly, not upgrade from 36**);

and from this link https://fedoramagazine.org/announcing-fedora-37/ I know that I'm using GNOME 43 on my computer.

but when I was checking my app store, I happened to find out that there are both **GNOME 42** and **GNOME 43** on my computer at the same time, together with other "pairs" like "**Freedesktop Platform**", "**Mesa**", "**openh264**", "**QGnomePlatform**"(even 3 of it), "**QGnomePlatform-decoration**".

[image: my application manager screen]
[image: my application manager screen]

They don't disappear after reboot. I'm confused about this.

What I want to know:

- Is such a thing normal ? what has caused this to happen ?
- Should I remove the old version of such packages manually ? Will manual removal do damage to the system ?
- If possible, I'm also willing to know about how these listed "duplicated" packages work.

I'm new in Linux, and I'd be so appreciated if there are any useful suggestions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) runtimes. They are installed to provide the expected runtime environments for Flatpak-packaged applications — some expect GNOME 42 libraries, others GNOME 43, etc. They aren’t used by the running desktop environment, which is GNOME 43 on Fedora 37.

You can clean up runtime environments that aren’t actually needed on your system by running

```
sudo flatpak uninstall --unused
```

in a terminal window. This won’t limit your future options: if you ever install a Flatpak which needs a missing runtime, all the missing components will be downloaded and installed for you.